Formatting a USB drive for SMB share, while keeping a folder hidden when connected to other PC's
I have an external 4TB USB drive I want to connect to a Raspberry Pi 5 to serve as a NAS for my local network, primarily using SMB.
I really want this drive to be possible to connect to a Windows PC also, so I guess exFAT is the filesystem to use in that case.
I have two folders, one "public" and one "private", these can be shared as two separate SMB shares.
If someone steals the drive, I want the "private" folder to be hidden/inaccessible.
NOTE: It doesn't need to be encrypted, I just don't want average joe to simply connect it to his PC and access the folder just like the rest of the folders.
(the possibility of finding the folder using advanced drive tools is acceptable).
Is this at all possible with exFAT, or do I need to give up on letting this drive be Windows accessible?

exFAT wouldn't be recommend, as it's a purpose-built filesystem for very large, single media files (such as video files) and is not intended to be used for anything but, which is why it has insanely large allocation unit sizes (IIRC, it;s ~64KB for a drive that large, versus 4KB for most other filesystems - e.g. a 1KB file takes up 64KB of space, and for all intents and purposes, a 4TB drive effectively becomes an ~250GB drive @ 64KB, ~500GB @32KB, ~1TB @16KB). Windows supports ext filesystems through WSL and Paragon's LinuxFS.

As to accessibility, unless the directory itself, or all files within, is/are encrypted, the average person will see both directories with a hidden attribute or not. Non-Windows OSes don't respect the hidden folder attribute and many, if not most, users have Show hidden files and directories enabled on Windows anyways. You may want to consider having the hidden directory be an encrypted disk image instead

@JW0914 I don't understand, you can choose the cluster size when you format it?

With all filesystems you can, however the smallest with exFAT is 16KB IIRC. Use ext3/4 or NTFS (Linux supports NTFS [ntfs-3g], whereas BSD doesn't)
